# Cascade delete of a parent entity with two children to the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade, one-to-one

I have two models:

**Child**

```
public class Child {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent**

```
public class Parent {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int? FirstChildId { get; set; }
   public Child FirstChild { get; set; }

   public int? SecondChildId { get; set; }
   public Child SecondChild { get; set; }
}
```

There is a strict relationship that one child has only one parent and one parent has zero-or-one `FirstChild` and zero-or-one `SecondChild`.

As far as I know, if we want to make a relationship to the same table (model) twice then we need to have a one-to-many relationship instead of one-to-one.

Therefore, I've modified the **Child** class by adding *Many* relationships.

```
public class Child {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Parent> ParentsFirstChild { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Parent> ParentsSecondChild { get; set; }
}
```

So far I have the next Fluent API `modelBuilder` that works

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
   .HasMany(f => f.ParentsFirstChild)
   .WithOptional(p => p.FirstChild)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.FirstChildId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
   .HasMany(f => f.ParentsSecondChild)
   .WithOptional(p => p.SecondChild)
   .HasForeignKey(p => p.SecondChildId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The problem is that if we'd put

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true)
```

It produces the error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   FK_dbo.Parent_dbo.Child_ParentsFirstChildId on table Parent may cause
>   cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I see that EF thinks that a Child could be related to other Parents. That's why it could be cyclic, right?

**Question**
How to create a mapping through either DataAnnotations or Fluent API, so that in case of presence (both optional) one or both children (same class/model) during deleting of a parent, children will be removed too?